# Sticky Navigation Bar Jumps on Scroll (JS, HTML, CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building this site as a fun little side project but I am stuck. My sticky nav bar jumps once the user scrolls far enough down. I have read other threads and can't quite connect the dots.

I have been thinking it must be a padding issue, however, my JS isn't all that great so there is potential for problems there as well.

Here is my Javascript:

```
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

var navbarHeight = navbar.offsetHeight;
var headerHeight = header.offsetHeight;

header.style.height = screen.height - navbarHeight;

function initJake() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > headerHeight) {
    navbar.style.position = "fixed";
    navbar.style.top = "0";

  } else {
    navbar.style.position = "relative";
  }
}
window.onscroll = function() {
  initJake()
};
```

Here is my jsFiddle (the links are cut off since this is the full-screen HTML setup): https://jsfiddle.net/jihlenfeldt/435ugdyf/2/

I am hoping to find a way in which the transition from absolute to fixed is smooth and doesn't end up covering a bunch of lines of text.

Thank you to anyone willing to offer a bit of advice, this little issue has become quite a headache.

Comment: Do you need to support IE? Because if not, you can just use the CSS property `position: sticky` to handle this for you instead of trying to recreate it in JS.

Comment: IE support is desired or else I would have gone that route. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?:

```
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var content = document.querySelector('#navbar + .content');



var navbarHeight = navbar.offsetHeight;
var headerHeight = header.offsetHeight;

header.style.height = screen.height-navbarHeight;

function initJake(){

    if(window.pageYOffset > headerHeight){

    navbar.style.position = "fixed";
    navbar.style.top = "0";
    content.style.padding = '60px 0 0 0';

}
else{

    navbar.style.position = "relative";
  content.style.padding = '0 0 0 0';

}

}


function hamburgerMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("submenu");
  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
} 



window.onscroll = function() {initJake()};
```

The issue here is that your navbar gets position "fixed" and its height is not considered by the DOM anymore since it'll be positioned "on top" of everything. Best way to fix this is to give the element after it (the content in this case) a padding-top of the same height that navbar has. (Unlike me, use a variable that gets the height of the navbar since its height can vary, not a fixed number like I did (the 60px))

Comment: Thanks, Daniel van der Velden! The variable in place of the pixel value was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Well here's your mistake.

```
if (window.pageYOffset > headerHeight) {
    navbar.style.position = "fixed";
    navbar.style.top = "0";
  } else {
    navbar.style.position = "relative"; // here 

  }
```

Your `navbar` has position `absolute` and when `window.pageYOffset > headerHeight` is false, you are making it `relative`

```css
#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #111;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition-property: width;
}
```

That's why the bump. Also, the navbar is fixed now, so It doesn't disturbs other elements. That's why the this div is covered by the navbar (or is going upwards)

```html
<div class="content">
    <h1>text here</h1>
    <p>text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here </p>
</div>
```

Possible fix is we stick to one position. Let's make it relative. Then we add margin top to the `content` div when the position is fixed. Which makes it some distance from above. So javascript becomes becomes

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
if (window.pageYOffset > headerHeight) {

    navbar.style.position = "fixed";
    navbar.style.top = "0";
    content.style.marginTop = " 115px";
  } else {

    navbar.style.position = "relative";
    content.style.marginTop = "0px";

  }
```

And stick to `relative` in css

```css
#navbar {
  position: relative;
...
}
```

So your [fiddle becomes something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/86vxahdw/)

Comment: Hindsight 20/20 that was such a silly thing to miss. This worked perfectly. I ended up employing a variable to get the margin height as suggested by Daniel van der Velden and it all flows very nicely now. Thank you so much for your support!

Answer (score -1):

Why do you guys use always JS to interact with the appearance of a HTML object.

Use JS to check if the header is outside of the viewport and if yes, set a class on the body. Via CSS you can modify the sticky header.
Something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(this).scrollTop() > $('#header').outerHeight()){ 
    $('body').addClass('scrolled');
  } else {
    $('body').removeClass('scrolled');
  }
});
```

And via CSS

```
#header { position:relative; }
body.scrolled #header { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; }
body.scrolled { padding-top:<Enter here Height of Header to prevent jumping> }
```

Comment: I wrote it using jQuery. But you can translate it to native JS.